# tmux shared socket throws "access not allowed" error

Tags: sockets, tmux, shared

I am using **tmux 3.3a** on an **Ubuntu 22.10** system with two users, bob and alice.
Both users are members of the `multiplexer` group.

Bob has created a tmux session on an custom socket like so:

```
tmux -S /tmp/our_socket new -s our_session
```

and then changed the group of the socket file to `multiplexer` and added read/write permissions for that group:

```
chgrp multiplexer /tmp/our_socket
chmod g+rw /tmp/our_socket
```

Now alice, who is also a member of the `multiplexer` group, is trying to connect to this session using:

```
tmux -S /tmp/our_socket attach -t our_session
```

which throws an `access not allowed` error.

However when alice uses `sudo`-privileges, she is able to connect to the tmux session.

I do not understand why access is denied without elevated privileges, as the socket file has read/write permissions for the `multiplexer` group and both bob and alice are members of that group. My guess is, that it's connected to the *sticky bit* enabled for the `/tmp` directory, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It seems that the later versions of tmux have its own access check as well. So, in addition to making the socket accessible to the user you want to share the session with, you also need to tell tmux that this user is allowed.

```
tmux server-access -a {user_to_share_with}
```

For more info, see the description of tmux "server-access" command.

P.S. As a bonus, the user can be allowed read-only access only now!

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your suggestion worked for me using tmux version 3.3a, i.e. `tmux server-access -a alice`. The previous version 3.2a does not require a user to be added to an access list for using shared sockets. I checked that as well.